# Incorrect application version "xxx" (deployment xxx) on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use Elastic Beanstalk for our NodeJs application. Sometimes an error message like this appears when I update some configurations like capacity:

```
Incorrect application version "release@016a2cd2-598187446" (deployment 34). Expected version "release@016a2cd2-598187446" (deployment 33).
```

I don't understand the error. The application version is the same. How can i fix this problem?

I have try to terminate EC2, rebuild the envinroment but the problem remain.

Answer (score 1):

A few possible solutions:

1. Check that you are using the correct Elastic Beanstalk URL. The URL for your Elastic Beanstalk environment will be in the format "http://xxxxxx-env.elasticbeanstalk.com". Make sure that you are using this URL, and not the URL for your S3 bucket (which will be in the format "http://xxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com").
2. If you are using a custom domain name for your Elastic Beanstalk environment, make sure that you have updated your DNS settings to point to the correct Elastic Beanstalk URL.
3. Make sure that you have deployed your application to the correct Elastic Beanstalk environment. You can check this by going to the "Elastic Beanstalk" tab in the AWS Management Console and selecting the environment that you want to deploy to. If you have multiple environments, make sure that you select the one that matches the URL that you are using.

Comment: 1./2. Yeah, the URL is correct. The problem is random, 99% of the time it happens without problems

3. The same version in currently deployed on another Elastic Beanstalk environment without problems. Now I've tried to redeploy the same version and seems it's all ok